# Is there some input condition for which `cin >> someStringValue` can evaulate to `false'?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

In `C++`, standard input stream i.e. `cin` could evaluate to `false` (via. implicit boolean conversion) if it finds an input value that is not matching with type of variable where input is going to be stored.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        cout << "valid integer input\n";
    }

    cout << "invalid integer input !!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Input/Output to above code,

Input,

```
12
13
15
ABC
```

Output,

```
valid integer input
valid integer input
valid integer input
invalid integer input !!
```

Here is my question,

As expected, If we give a non-numeric input in above scenario then `cin` evaluates to false and program ends there. But what if I use a `string` variable in-place of integer variable in above code then what could be possible input value which I can provide so that `cin` evaluates to `false`? Because when I try above piece of code with a `string` variable instead of int then while-loop never seems to end ...

Comment: I'd assume inputting a control character would result in `false` as it has no string representation.

Comment: If you enter more characters than the buffer can hold.

Comment: User generating a manual `EOF`, e.g. `Ctrl+d` on Linux, `Ctrl+z` on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `cin >> x` returns `cin`, so you check the boolean value of `cin`.

An iostream has [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) define as:

> Checks whether the stream has no errors.
>
> …
> 2. Returns true if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.
>
> This operator makes it possible to use streams and functions that return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`. Such loops execute the loop's body only if the input operation succeeded.

In the case of an `int` it fails for `ABC` because `ABC` cannot be converted to int. Another situation when `cin` would evaluate to false is when the input stream closes.

Comment: so does that mean that giving 'end-of-input` character as input to program which ctrl+Z character , correct ?? All other characters will be considered as valid string values and while-loop won't end .

Comment: @PravarJawalekar I don't know it by heart right now, and I have to look it up, but I would assume that's the case.

Comment: Ctrl+Z on some platforms (CP/M, MS-DOS, MS-Windows, OS/2), Ctrl+D on other platforms (Amiga, Unix, Linux, FreeBSD), and probably other things on other platforms.

Comment: @PravarJawalekar I believe if you hit EOF without reading any characters it will set the fail flag.

Comment: Also, if stdin is redirected at the command line to read from a file, you can reach the end of the file without having to type anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that sometimes with the string input loop (like the while loop), "end-of-file" would still be recognized as a string input rather than a command to signal the end of your data input. Therefore I usually use if-else to manually set the string "end-of-file" (or basically anything) as the end of my data input. For example I would re-write your code like this for the string case (the int case would be similar):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    string eof("end-of-file");
    while (cin >> s) {
        if (s != eof) { // the "!=" operator means "different from"
            cout << "valid-string-input" << endl;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "invalid string input" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: you should be aware that while an int cannot be a string, a string can be almost anything, even a number says "10" or "1" could still be considered a valid string input, it's just that these "10" or "1" cannot perform arithmetic operations since they are not ints. So the "invalid string input" here might be a little bit harder to trigger compared to the int case.

Short explanation for return 0, which basically means the program will be recognized as successful and will end right there. So the else {return 0;} means if the string is "end-of-file" then the program would just stop right there and recognized as successfully operated/ran.